# My boost managed_shared_memory does not seem to unmap from memory space when leaving scope

Tags: c++, memory, boost, memory-leaks, shared-memory

I realized I have a strange kind of *memory leak* using boost managed_shared_memory.

After opening or creating a shared memory, once it goes out of scope, the amount of memory held by my process does not decrease.

Here is a sample reproducing the problem :

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::interprocess;
using namespace boost::container;

int main()
{

  string shMemName = "name";

  // Remove shared memory to reset example
  shared_memory_object::remove(shMemName.c_str());

  if (true) // Local scope
  {
    // Create shared memory
    managed_shared_memory managed_shm{ open_or_create, shMemName.c_str(), 100000000 };

    // Adding something random to take up most of the place in the memory
    vector<short>* sharedVector = managed_shm.construct<vector<short>>(shMemName.c_str()) (); 
    sharedVector->resize(40000000);
  } // <--- I expect to lose access to the shared memory therefore having it unmapped

  // Even if I remove the shared memory, there seems to still be a leak
  bool success = shared_memory_object::remove(shMemName.c_str());

  std::cout << "Done " << success << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(50));

  // If we check the amount of memory used by the process, it is > 80 Mb

  return 0;
}
```

Instead of removing the shared memory, deleting the vector in it using the following seems to free the memory effectivly :

```
managed_shm.destroy<vector<short>>(shMemName.c_str());
```

However, this is not what I am trying to achieve. I would like it to still be in memory, just unmapped to the process that created it.

Why doesn't leaving the scope unmap the shared memory ? Do I have to make something specific, and if so, what is it ?

EDIT :

Modified sample to make the program crash by saturation of memory :

```
int main()
{
  string shMemName = "name";
  shared_memory_object::remove(shMemName.c_str());

  for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) // 500 should make it crash on any computer
  {                             // unless you have way too much RAM
    // Create shared memory
    managed_shared_memory managed_shm{ open_or_create, shMemName.c_str(), 100000000 };

    // Adding something random to take up most of the place in the memory
    vector<short>* sharedVector = managed_shm.construct<vector<short>>(shMemName.c_str()) ();
    sharedVector->resize(40000000);

    // Remove memory
    bool success = shared_memory_object::remove(shMemName.c_str());

    std::cout << "Is removal of shared memory successful ?"
      << "(If 1 yes, if 0 no) : " << success << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The shared memory is always removed and recreated. It should not leak anything... but it does.

Comment: "When the `managed_shared_memory` object is destroyed, the shared memory object is automatically unmapped, and all the resources are freed." - From [the doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html) - seems to contradict the sample code.

Comment: How are you measuring the amount of memory? This is most likely observer error, because it's really hard to get accurate page info for processes on most operating systems

Comment: @sehe I am using the windows ressource monitor. If I try to do `managed_shm.destroy<vector<short>>(shMemName.c_str());` I can see the memory going back to almost nothing. However, leaving the scope or `shared_memory_object::remove(shMemName.c_str());` does not seem to affect how much memory holds the process, even if the later remove function returns indeed that removal was a success.

Comment: By looping on this example, you can actually crash the program by saturation of memory. Even though we call remove and reopen always a memory with same name (so, no duplicate is possible), the memory ends up lacking hence showing that letting managed_shared_memory going out of scope is not enough to unmap it from memory space, despite what the doc states.

Comment: I added the code sample that crashes when no more memory is available for the process. I guess it is a better example. It might rule out observer error possibility.

Comment: Hah.

It was dead simple. I just forgot to look at the data structure before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vector /instance/ is in shared memory, but all element data is not. Because you don't use a shared memory allocator. Instead of `std::vector<T>`  use `std::vector<T, myallocator>` where `myallocator` allocates from the shared memory.

E.g.:

**<kbd>Live On Coliru</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using ShMem = bip::managed_shared_memory;
using Vec = bip::vector<short, bip::allocator<short, ShMem::segment_manager> >;

int main()
{
    std::string shMemName = "name";
    bip::shared_memory_object::remove(shMemName.c_str());

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) // 500 should make it crash on any computer
    {                             // unless you have way too much RAM
        {
            // Create shared memory
            bip::managed_shared_memory managed_shm{ bip::create_only, shMemName.c_str(), 100000000 };

            // Adding something random to take up most of the place in the memory
            Vec& sharedVector = *managed_shm.construct<Vec>("vecname") (managed_shm.get_segment_manager());
            sharedVector.resize(40000000);
        }

        // Remove memory
        bool success = bip::shared_memory_object::remove(shMemName.c_str());

        std::cout << "Is removal of shared memory successful? " << std::boolalpha << success << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that there was a slight issue with the `remove` in the loop being before the destructor of the `managed_shared_memory` object.

Comment: I see. However there is still something I don't get. In my original example, if I do `sharedVector->resize(0);` or swap with empty vector before destroying the shared memory, there is still a leak. Is it because an object allocated on managed_shared_memory should not have any of its components allocated outside the shared memory (because boost presumably does not handle it) ?

Comment: Should I create a new question specifically for this to present it in a more understandable way ?

Comment: I think so, yes.